# How many ways we can partition a multiset, where each part/segment in the partition has distinct elements?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity

We define the set S as $\{(s_1, f_1), (s_2, f_2), ..., (s_i, f_i)\}$, where each $f_i$ is the frequency that $s_i$ is repeated in the multiset T. How many ways can we partition the multiset T into different partitions, where each partition includes distinct part/segments?

For example, given $S = \{(s_1, 1), (s_2, 2), (s_3, 1)\}$ results in the multiset $T = \{s_1, s_2, s_2, s_3\}$, where s1 is repeated once, s2 is repeated twice, and s3 repeated once in the multiset. Now, we can partition the multiset into six different partitions, where each partition includes distinct parts/segments as follows:

1:$\{\{s_1,s_2\},\{s_2,s_3\}\}$

2:$\{\{s_1,s_2,s_3\},\{s_2\}\}$

3:$\{\{s_1,s_2\},\{s_2\},\{s_3\}\}$

4:$\{\{s_1\},\{s_2\},\{s_2,s_3\}\}$

5:$\{\{s_1,s_3\},\{s_2\}, \{s_2\}\}$

6:$\{\{s_1\},\{s_2\},\{s_2\},\{s_3\}\}$

- Note that the order of elements in each segment does not matter, e.g., $\{s_1, s_2\} = \{s_2, s_1\}$
- Note that each subset has different/distinct elements.

Now, I am looking for **a formula** that counts the number of partitions of the set T, where $S = \{(s_1, f_1), (s_2, f_2), ..., (s_i, f_i)\}$. I am curious to know if it is possible to compute it in terms of the number of elements in the set S and the corresponding frequencies.

Comment: This is a site for math questions. If you give the algorithm in clear, mostly English pseudo-code, we can analyze its runtime. But we will not read Javascript for you.

Comment: @Mike: Thank you very much for your feedback. May I ask you what is the complexity of the algorithm I asked in the question apart from the pseudo-code I attached here?

Comment: I can't understand what the algorithm is, so I cannot answer. If you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4622246/edit) your question to include an intuitive description of what the algorithm is doing, then maybe I or someone else can help.

Comment: @Mike: I edited the question as you asked. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: I have an answer to this but with four close votes I am doubting whether to post. Maybe OP could improve the write-up and try again.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4622246/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/157017/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Having two identical elements s_2 in your multiset T is a nonsense isn't it? Either they are the same and T has three elements, or they are distinct, say s_2_1 and s_2_2 in which case you're not merely looking for partitions of T because, for example, you want to treat {{s_1, s_2_1}{s_2_2}{s_3}} and {{s_1, s_2_2}{s_2_1}{s_3}} as equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved using the Polya Enumeration Theorem. We get
very straightforwardly that the desired quantity is given by where
$F = f_1+f_2+\cdots+f_n$

$$\sum_{k=1}^F
[A_1^{f_1} A_2^{f_2} \times\cdots\times A_n^{f_n}]
Z\left(S_k; -1 + \prod_{q=1}^n (1+A_q)\right).$$

where we refer to the cycle index of the symmetric group. We now use the
recurrence  by Lovasz  for the  cycle index  $Z(S_k)$ of  the multiset
operator      $\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}     \def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm
#1{\small #2}}} \textsc{MSET}_{=k}$ on $k$ slots, which is

$$Z(S_k) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{\ell=1}^k  a_\ell Z(S_{k-\ell})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$

Next we introduce $T(Q, k)$ where $Q$ is a monomial in the variables
$A_q$  and $k$ is a non-negative integer and

$$T(Q, k) = [Q] Z(S_k; -1 + \prod_{A\in Q} (1+A)).$$

We also put

$$S(Q) = -1 + \prod_{A\in Q} (1+A).$$

These are the sets that go into the $k$ slots.
We thus obtain from the Lovasz recurrence a recurrence for $T:$

$$T(Q, k) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{\ell=1}^k
\sum_{P\in S(Q)}' T(Q/P^\ell, k-\ell).$$

The mark on the sum signifies two things, first we only recurse when
$Q/P^\ell$ is a proper monomial including the value one and second, that
all monomials are  represented by a product

$$A_1^{g_1} A_2^{g_2} \times \cdots \times A_p^{g_p}$$

with the degree sequence $g_1\le g_2\le\cdots\le g_p$ in increasing
order. This is so that we may  properly memoize the recurrence as the
result only depends on the  partition induced by the monomials (order of
variables does not  matter). We can take the recurrence for $T$ and more
or less translate  it directly into CAS code, we just have to take care
of the base cases,  the most important of which is that when we have
reached only one  variable then we get a contribution of one if and only
if the degree of  the variable equals $k$, and zero otherwise. That is
all, if we are  after a total count we just add the values for the
parameter $k.$

We can use the following special multisets to compute some example 
values, where there are $n$ elements in the multiset and $m$ copies of 
each element. For example, with $n=7$ elements and $m=3$ copies of each 
we have for the possible values starting with $k=3$ and going to $k=21$ 
the sequence

$$1, 714, 84000, 1737813, 11673597, 35162333, 57789691, 59078859, 
\\ 41165320, 20857585, 8046164, 2441211, 595456, 
\\ 118300, 19236, 2541, 266, 21, 1.$$

The reader may want to use this to verify their computations. Another
example is for $n=6$ elements and $m=4$ copies of each we get with $k$
rangeing from $k=4$ to $k=24$:

$$1, 201, 18171, 396571, 3053216, 11003801, 22360580, 29114463, 
\\ 26607981, 18227245, 9816458, 4301588, 1572206, 487670, 
\\ 129880, 29828, 5901, 995, 140, 15, 1.$$

Another important sanity check is  that we should get Stirling numbers
of the second kind when $m=1$ and indeed this check also goes through.
The Maple  code shown below  implements three routines. First  a plain
enumeration routine that can be used to verify correctness of the more
sophisticated   alternatives.   Second,   computation  by   the  Polya
Enumeration  Theorem  directly  substituting   into  the  cycle  index
$Z(S_k)$  and third,  the recurrence  described above.  The number  of
entries in the memoization table for $T$  is given by the value of the
partition function  summed for up  to the  total degree of  the inital
value of $Q.$ This is the code:

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm_maxcl :=
proc(n, m)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm_maxcl(n-l, m),
                   l=1..min(m,n)));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

# Polya Enumeration Theorem
T1 :=
proc(n, k, m)
option remember;
local rep, q, p, gf;

    rep := -1 + mul(1+A[q], q=1..n);
    gf := pet_varinto_cind(rep, pet_cycleind_symm_maxcl(k, m));

    for q to n do
        gf := diff(gf, A[q]$m);
        gf := 1/m!*subs(A[q]=0, gf);
    od;

    gf;
end;


# sanity check for small arguments of the parameters
ENUM :=
proc(n, k, m)
option remember;
local mset, allmsets, idx, digits, dix, src, sidx;

    if k=1 then return 1 fi;

    src := [seq(V[q]$m, q=1..n)];
    allmsets := table();

    for idx from k^(m*n) to 2*k^(m*n)-1 do
        digits := convert(idx, `base`, k)[1..m*n];
        if nops(convert(digits, `set`)) = k then
            mset := table([seq(q=1, q=1..k)]);
            for sidx to m*n do
                dix := digits[sidx] + 1;

                if src[sidx] in indets(mset[dix]) then
                    break;
                fi;

                mset[dix] := mset[dix] * src[sidx];
            od;

            if sidx = m*n+1 then
                allmsets[sort([entries(mset, `nolist`)])] := 1;
            fi;
        fi;
    od;

    numelems(allmsets);
end;

dgseq :=
proc(ms)
local vars, var, ds, q;
    vars := indets(ms);
    ds := sort([seq(degree(ms, var), var in vars)]);
    mul(A[q]^ds[q], q=1..nops(vars));
end;


T2gen :=
proc(ms, k)
option remember;
local vars, var, rep, term, res, sbms, ell;

    vars := indets(ms);

    if nops(vars) = 0 and k = 0 then
        return 1;
    elif nops(vars) = 0 or k=0 then
        return 0;
    fi;

    if nops(vars) = 1 then
        if degree(ms) = k then
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
        fi;
    end;

    rep := -1 + expand(mul(1+var, var in vars));
    res := 0;

    for ell to k do
        for term in rep do
            sbms := ms/term^ell;
            if type(sbms, `polynom`) then
                res := res + T2gen(dgseq(sbms), k-ell);
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    res/k;
end;

T2 :=
proc(n,k,m)
    local q;
    T2gen(mul(A[q]^m, q=1..n), k);
end;
```

Comment: Marko Riedel: May I ask if it is possible to give an upper bound for the total number of partitions? In fact, I am curious what is the computation complexity for calculating the total number of partitions using an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Marko Riedel: I have attached a code that computes the total possible partitions, which is for the set $S=(s1,3),(s2,4),(s3,5)$
 equals 66. Could you please check if your formula results in the same number? Sorry as the formula is heavy for me, I requested this.

Comment: Yes I have checked this example and I get $66$ as well using add(T2gen(A[1]^3*A[2]^4*A[3]^5, k), k=1..12);

Comment: Marko Riedel: Thank you for checking and validating. I asked a relevant question in the below link. Could you please help me with this?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624364/is-there-any-upper-bound-for-the-number-of-ways-we-can-partition-a-multiset-whe

Comment: Marko Riedel: Could you please explain an efficient algorithm's complexity for the partitioning I explained above? I asked this question in the below link to make it separate from the current one.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624364/is-there-any-upper-bound-for-the-number-of-ways-we-can-partition-a-multiset-whe

Comment: Marko Riedel: Could you please elaborate more on what $A_n$ is, and what is the intuition behind the below formula? Its understanding is not straightforward for me, at least. Thanks

$$\sum_{k=1}^F
[A_1^{f_1} A_2^{f_2} \times\cdots\times A_n^{f_n}]
Z\left(S_k; -1 + \prod_{q=1}^n (1+A_q)\right).$$